# Using cin for input complex number in C++11

Tags: c++11, complex-numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    complex<double> p;
    cin >> p.real() >> p.imag();
}
```

In g++4.7.2 it works successfully, but in C++11 failed to compile. Why?

It gives me following error message:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:7:19: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cin >> p.std::complex<double>::real()’
```

Full version: http://ideone.com/M3BhVR

Comment: too long error message.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it even simpler like this:

```
cin >> p;
```

Format must be: (real,imag) (see: [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_ltltgtgt))

Or you can do the following:

```
double real, imag;
cin >> real >> imag;
complex<double> p(real, imag);
```

Comment: gave you an alternative. the problem is you can't use the real() and imag() accessors because the return a copy and not a reference so you wouldn't actually be modifying the complex number but rather temporary doubles.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `p.real()` and `p.imag()` do not return references, so they are temporary values and it doesn't make sense to write to temporaries.

Comment: Which makes the "works successfully in gcc 4.7.2" a little suspect.  I suspect the poster just meant "works without visible error" and didn't validate the complex value produced.

Comment: i always use this notation to deal with space-separated value in C++.